# Isspace Character Function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm new to this and currently studying C++. I'm currently learning about Character Functions in cctype(ctype). I'm having trouble understanding why the  isspace(a_character) is not returning my cout message -- the problem is it wont even accept my Char user input. Any help or steering to the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I can achieve the response I want if I assign the Char value of: ' ' , however, it defeats the purpose. I've copied a portion of my code. To my understanding, there's no exact symbol for Whitespace? if so, is it possible to even enter a whitespace as an input? I've tried entering : ' ' however, have not been successful. Again, I'd greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype> 
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   char c ;   
   char ans = 'y' || 'Y';

   do {
      cout << "Enter a character \n";
      cin >> c;

      if (isspace (c))  //Having trouble get this to actually produce a value
      {
         cout << "Your character " << c << "is a whitespace";
      }

      if (ispunct(c))
      {
         cout << c << " is a punctuation character\n";
      }

      cout << "Would you like to enter another value? \n";
      cin >> ans;

   } while (ans == 'Y' || ans == 'y');

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char ans = 'y' || 'Y';` Huh?

Comment: For my do while loop to prompt the user if they'd like to repeat the program

Comment: `'y' || 'Y'` is, simply, `true`.

Comment: how embarrassing, I see what you both mean. Thanks for the tangent fix!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`>>` is a formatted extractor. Formatted extractors, by default, extract and discard all whitespace characters before they actually read anything. That's useful behavior, but not when you are trying to read a whitespace character.

Either use unformatted input (`get()`) or the `noskipws` manipulator. Note that your later reading of `ans` in all likelihood depends on *skipping whitespace* to work correctly, so you'd probably want to restore the whitespace-skipping behavior with `skipws` after you read `c` if you choose the second option.

Comment: It's people like you that help me sleep at night. A side note though, and something I'll further explore: I decided to remove the do while loop as it gave me trouble (as you predicted) even when using the: cin.get(c)>>skipws; manipulator. I'm curious as to why, even though i included it after the cin member function

Comment: @Rod 1) If you use `get()` (which is unformatted and doesn't auto-skip whitespace) then you don't need to `skipws`. 2) I suspect the problem is that the newline left in the input buffer got read in the second iteration. One possibility is to use `ws` or `ignore` to discard it before re-printing the prompt.